# Union of two XML schemas

Tags: xml, xsd

I want a way to find the union of two XML schemas. Is there a standard way of doing it? If not please give your ideas

What I want is like :

Schema1:

```
<xs:schema>
 <xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="a"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="b"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Schema2:

```
<xs:schema>
 <xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="c"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="d"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The Union would be something like

```
<xs:schema>
 <xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="a" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="b" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="c" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="d" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I do not mind if the union schema validates more XML than the initial two schema, I just want a compact schema which validates all the XML validated by the initial two schema

Please discuss various possible schema unions.